# Python Split strings

Tags: python, curl

I am trying to read a file and out put the results. 
my file **test.txt**
ravi, curl
charan, git
I need to print it as below
**- {Username: "ravi" , Application: curl}
- {Username: "charan" , Application: git}**

I am trying as follows

```
    file = open("test.txt", "r")
    for line in file.readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        parts = line.split("\n")
        for part in parts:
            print ("-" + "{" + "Username:" + "" + part[0:4] + " " + "Application:" + part[5:9] + "}")
```

Ouput:
**-{Username:ravi Application:curl}
-{Username:char Application:n,gi}**

Please let me know how can I modify the code to get the Ou put in below format.

- {Username: "ravi" , Application: curl}
- {Username: "charan" , Application: git}

Comment: use “”“ instead of “”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        line = re.findall('(\w+)', line)
        print '{Username:"%s", Application:%s}' % (line[0], line[1])
        print '{Username:"%s", Application:%s}' % (line[2], line[3])
```

Comment: Thyank you Ankur, I tried to execute above code, I got below error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/Test1.py", line 3, in <module>
    line = re.findall('(\w+)' , line)
NameError: name 're' is not defined

Comment: you need to import re module

Comment: I used re module, still I got below error. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/Test1.py", line 34, in <module>
    print '{Username:"%s", Application:%s}' % (line[2], line[3])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: If you have just two words per line then remove the last line of the code I gave you. My code is as per **four words per line** like, 
**ravi, curl charan, git**

Answer (score 1):

change your print to this

```
print ('- ' + '{' + 'Username: ' + '"' + part[0:4] + '" ' + 'Application: ' + part[5:9] + '} ')
```

if you want to print double quotes you can either escape a double quote like this: `"\""` or wrap it in single quotes like this `'"'`

because I stuck with the single quote method I also changed all of your quotes to be single quotes for consistency sake

Answer (score 0):

It unclear how your file is actually formatted, although for a string formatted like your example:

```
one, two three, four
```

You would likely want to split it up differently to make it easier to manage, this way you don't need to worry about the exact length of the split portion of the string. Another thing to consider is the way you are outputting the result — as you have it now is very confusing and prone to encounter issues if one quote is misplaced. **Use a format string instead**!

```
s = ['one, two three, four']

for line in s:
    line = line.replace(', ',':')
    part = line.split(' ')
    for name in part:
        half = name.split(':')
        print ('-{{Username:"{0}", Application:{1}}}'.format(half[0], half[1]))
```

**Result**:

```
-{Username:"one", Application:two}
-{Username:"three", Application:four}
```

Comment: Thank you, this code works fine. However my data is not in a single line ravi,curl are in one line charan,git are in next line

Answer (score 0):

My final codes that worked well are.

```
import re
with open("test.txt", "r") as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        line = re.findall('(\w+)', line)
        print ' - {Username: '"%s"' , Application: %s}' % (line[0], line[1])
```

Code 2

```
file = open("test.txt" , "r")
for line in file.readlines():
    data = line.strip().split(',')
    print ("-" + " " + "{" + "Username:\"" + data[0] + "\", " + "Application:" + data[1] + "}")
```